# convert 2.5VAC to 5V DC wave

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, ac, dc

I have converted mains from 240V RMS (330V) AC @ 50Hz to 2.5V AC using a transformer and am now trying to put the wave into an ADC that operates at 0-5V.

I am looking to convert a 1.76V RMS (2.5V) AC @ 50Hz (5V pp) sin wave into a 5V DC sin wave (5V pp), i know i require an op amp although i'm pulling blanks from my mind. Thanks for all the help. The reason is is i need to input the wave into an ADC that operated between 0-5V.

At this point i guess i need a summing amplifier that acts as a DC level control.

Comment: Can you clarify what type of output  you want? "DC" and "wave" are incompatible. I am guessing you want to convert a 5V sine wave into a 5V square wave of the same frequency? Or maybe just rectify the AC to DC, in which case there is no wave (and pp is zero, because the output is static).

Comment: no it has to be the same sin wave just converted into a DC wave that i can input into an ADC

Comment: Why don't you just feed the waveform directly to the ADC? Seems like it would be easier.

Comment: If the frequency range is not too great, a transformer will work just fine, and will not require an external power supply.

Comment: What frequency? If the frequency is high enough, just couple through a capacitor and re-bias at 2.5 V.

Comment: The frequency is at 50Hz

Comment: I guess you just want to add a 2.5V DC offset to your sine wave? Such as described here under "Summing Amplifier"? http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Amplifiers/amplifiers66.php

Comment: What is the input impedance of the ADC? Or max leakage current?

Comment: A summing amplifier would require a negative rail. If one is available, that would be a good solution. To the OP, what voltages are available?

Comment: max leakage is 10uA and the voltages available are 5V and 0V

Comment: Also be careful that 2.5V AC waveform really is 5Vp-p or less. If it was 2.5Vrms it would exceed the permitted ADC input voltage.

Comment: Fixed to make it clear, its 1.76V RMS (2.5V)

Comment: The exact step-down ratio of the transformer may not be controlled to a tight tolerance. You don't say what your intention is in feeding this signal to an ADC. But if you want to calculate actual mains voltage amplitude based on this, you will need to carefully verify that it works correctly over the range of voltages you want. You might need to supply a calibration factor for the system.

Comment: Why does a summing amplifier require a negative rail? Just take a rail to rail in/out amplifier and you won't need a negative supply..

Comment: And moreover... this is fine if you want to record the full wave. If you want to implement a zero-crossing control, just use a comparator (faster and more robust)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit creates a 5V peak DC sine wave.

[image: Op Amp Adder Circuit]

Can someone check this circuit please. All my simulations lead me to believe that this is the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you AC couple the signal to the ADC. This will create a high-pass effect, which, hopefully, will be acceptable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAb9r3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The high-pass frequency is controlled by R1, R2 and C1. You have to use the parallel combination of R1 and R2 (5k) for the RC calculation. In this case, the cutoff frequency of the high-pass filter is around 3 Hz. So 50 Hz will pass with very little attenuation.

Another thing to consider is that the source of the 50 Hz signal will see this as a 5k load. I do not know if that will be a problem because you have not mentioned where the 50 Hz signal is coming from. Assuming it can supply 1mA pp without sagging, there should be no problem.

You could make R1 and R2 larger (47k, or 100k) but then the effect of the 10 uA max leakage current might become a problem. I chose 10k to make sure that effect would be negligible.

### **Addendum about Mains Power:**

Mains voltage is not well regulated. I would suggest you attenuate the signal further before sending it to the ADC, or add robust over-voltage protection to the ADC input. Also, for safety, make sure your step-down transformer provides good isolation. You should also probably have a fuse on the secondary side of the transformer. I am not an expert on mains powered equipment, but there are many safety hazards associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you have a sin wave that goes from +2.5V to -2.5V and you want to convert it to go from 0V to +5V?

How about this...?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAPrRu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Produces this output...

[image]